# C++: where are my new nodes?

Tags: c++, set, binary-tree

I am trying to add element in a Set using Binary Tree:

```
bool TreeSet::add(const string &str)
{
    if (treesize == 0)
    {
        TreeNode->data = str;
        treesize++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (str < TreeNode->data)
            return insert(TreeNode->left, str);
        else if (str > TreeNode->data)
            return insert(TreeNode->right, str);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

bool TreeSet::insert(TREE *node, const string &str) //private
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        node = new TREE;
        node->data=str;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        treesize++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (str < node->data)
            return insert(node->left, str);
        else if (str > node->data)
            return insert(node->right, str);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, I want to initialize a TREE struct inside of insert and when I finish doing this I want to link it with the left or right node of the tree.

But when I gdb this, only 1 level of tree (top level) can be constructed, the `*left` and `*right` node are `NULL` no matter how many strings I was trying to add to it. Why?

My TREE is:

```
typedef struct tree
{
    string data;
    tree *left;
    tree *right;
} TREE;
```

Comment: Probably you have some [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool TreeSet::insert(TREE *node
```

should be

```
bool TreeSet::insert(TREE *&node
```

Pointers can also be passed by reference, and should be if you intend to modify them directly. Otherwise you pass by copy and you now have two pointers pointing at the same location. When you use the copied one to `new` up some data, it now points to a new memory location, leaving your original pointer still as `NULL` (`nullptr` in C++11)

---

On a side note, when a tree gets constructed, you should probably initialize `left` and `right` to `NULL` (`nullptr` in C++11):

```
typedef struct tree
{
    string data;
    tree *left;
    tree *right;
    tree():left(NULL),right(NULL){}
} TREE;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have its class constructor initialize to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a pointer as a parameter in the function `insert` like this:

```
bool TreeSet::insert(TREE* node, const string& str);
```

then the pointer is *copied* into the  argument `node`. Pointing `node` to something else only points the local copy of the pointer. The pointer passed  to the function from the call site is **unchanged**.

```
node = new TREE; // Points local variable 'node' to newly allocated data.
                 // When the function goes out of scope 'node' will be destroyed
                 // and the memory will be leaked.
```

To change where the original call site pointer points, take the parameter by **reference** (or add another level of indirection):

```
bool TreeSet::insert(TREE*& node, const string& str);
```

By taking a parameter by reference, you make sure you are accessing the call site variable and not a local copy.